# strtotime returns false on certain dates

Tags: php, strtotime

I check [here](https://ru.functions-online.com/strtotime.html) my `strtotime` function:
11/2/2016 returns timestamp but some dates higher returns false. 12/2/2016 is false however 2016-2-12 returns timestamp. WTF? That's not problem for me to past them but according to [docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.date.php) it's fine format.

Comment: share your code how you are using strtotime ?

Comment: Tested it and works fine: `echo strtotime('12/2/2016');`

Comment: `'13/2/2016'` will return a false, because there is no month 13 in any year, but `'12/2/2016'` should be perfectly valid and return the timestamp for 2nd December 2016. However, I would suggest reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for an explanation of formats that are recognised by the strtotime() function

Comment: Please note that `strototime` expects to be given a string containing an **English date format**

Comment: @fusion3k that's not true, take a look at note #3 according to the documentation a `/` separator is assumed US format, whilst a `-` is assumed EU/UK format.

Comment: So, the problem is that the moth go first??

Comment: @ash you are right in the context of this question. But generally, `strtotime` accepts strings in English (US or UK): so, i.e., '2015.12.01' and '01 avr 2015' are not recognized. This by precision, not to contest your comment, that is totally right in this context.

Comment: @SergeyScopin - month is assumed first if you have a `/` separator; day is assumed first if you have a `-` separator, as clearly stated in the PHP Docs on date formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have such problem on our project and we solve it by using `DateTime::createFromFormat`

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '12/2/2016');
// now you can receive absolutely correct timestamp
$dateTime->getTimestamp()
```